# PHP MySQL search function

Tags: php, mysql, function, search, sql-like

I am doing a blog for a school project and I am just about done, I want to add a search function and I ran in to some problems, it's probably not very hard to solve though.

So I will post my code below and explain I guess.

**Header.php** //requierd on every page, it's a template

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**Index.php** //Where I want the results to be displayed.

```
$searchword = $_POST['search'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postID desc LIMIT $start, $limit");

if ($searchword != "") {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE text LIKE '%$searchword%' ORDER BY postID desc LIMIT " . $start, $limit);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{ //This is where all the blog posts are outputted. 
  //And where I want the results to show up as well, but instead of all posts, 
  //when something is searched for, if possible.
```

Okey, so the problem is that I dont know how to do the $query.
I tried this with the

```
action="anotherpage.php"
```

and wrote the query like this

```
$searchword = $_POST['search'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE text LIKE '%$searchword%'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

it worked but I preferably do not want to open another page to display the results, and now on the index.php page I do not know how to do since I have

```
LIMIT " . $start, $limit); //for my pagination.
and
ORDER BY //in the query as well, I cant get it to work.
```

also, I tried

```
if (!empty($searchword)) //Dont really know if that's how you do it, but didn't work either
```

I hope I provided enough information. 
Basically I want to see all my posts on my first page, and if I search for something I want to display the results only but on the same page and with my pagination.
And by the way, this site is not going online, just a school project so dont worry to much about sql injection and what not.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to dynamically add the search results to the current page? Sounds like you need to learn AJAX. Start here: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Well, I dont know, I have done this before in cshtml, It's just that when something is posted in the searchbox the query changes to where the blog text contains the searched word(s)

Answer (score 2):

Your action should be like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
        // ..form fields..

</form>
```

which will always post back to the current page.

Comment: You need the `<?php ... ?>` code tag around the echo statement.

Comment: Was stuck for a whole day at a point. This solved it. Thankyouuu